# How do I create a pagefile for memory dumps only?

Tags: windows, windows-10, bsod, pagefile, minidumps

In case of a blue screen I would like to get a memory dump (specifically a mini dump). But for that I would need to enable page file which I don't want to do.

However, I've read somewhere that there is an option to create a page file dedicated to memory dumps. Unfortunately that source didn't have an explanation of how to do that. Unfortunately #2 I don't remember the url for that source.

So the bottom line is: how do I create a pagefile for memory dumps only?

**EDIT**

The source is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/performance/how-to-determine-the-appropriate-page-file-size-for-64-bit-versions-of-windows#dedicated-dump-files). Unfortunately, the link that MS says shows how to create it does not show that (or at least I didn't find how to).

Comment: On a related note, I **strongly** suggest you enable the page file to stop wasting RAM.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot decide what a page file is used for.

You either refuse to enable the page file and accept that you are crippling the virtual memory system unnecessarily, and in doing so preventing the memory dump system from working, or you enable the page file and allow it to work as intended including allowing memory dumps.

From [How to determine the appropriate page file size for 64-bit versions of Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/performance/how-to-determine-the-appropriate-page-file-size-for-64-bit-versions-of-windows) in Home or user editions of Windows you can set a minimal page file which will allow *certain types* of memory dump to happen if needed, but you cannot restrict the page file for those situations alone.

> | System crash dump setting | Minimum page file size requirement |
> | --- | --- |
> | Small memory dump (256 KB) | 1 MB |
> | Kernel memory dump | Depends on kernel virtual memory usage |
> | Complete memory dump | 1 x RAM plus 257 MB* |
> | Automatic memory dump | Depends on kernel virtual memory usage. For details, see Automatic memory dump. |

For Windows Server you *can* set a dedicated page file for dump files:

> #### Dedicated dump files
>
> Computers that are running Microsoft Windows or Microsoft Windows Server usually must have a page file to support a system crash dump. System administrators can now create a dedicated dump file instead.
>
> A dedicated dump file is a page file that isn't used for paging. Instead, it is "dedicated" to back a system crash dump file (Memory.dmp) when a system crash occurs. Dedicated dump files can be put on any disk volume that can support a page file. **We recommend that you use a dedicated dump file if you want a system crash dump but you don't want a page file**. To learn how to create it, see [Overview of memory dump file options for Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/performance/memory-dump-file-options).

More information is at [Configure memory dump files for Server Core installation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/server-core/server-core-memory-dump).

Comment: Thank you. That is the source I saw. And as you can read in the quote you copied: `...Microsoft Windows or Microsoft Windows Server...can now create a dedicated dump file instead.` - so not only Windows Server. Unfortunately, the link that MS says shows `how to create it` does not show that (or at least I didn't find how to).

Comment: @ispiro [How](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/server-core/server-core-memory-dump) is most certainly documented. However, I **do not believe** what you want to do is a feature of a consumer version of Windows.

Comment: @Mokubai I took a look at the last link you posted and I have a question about it, since that seems to be explaining more or less how to set up the dedicated page file. Why does it set the size of the dump file twice (in steps 2 and 7) and also sets the dump type (in step 3) which should automatically set the dump size and make both of the other ones unneeded?

Comment: @ispiro to me step 7 is more "check that the setup worked using this command (and by the way here's a second way to set the size if you missed it earlier)" than setting it twice. As for step 3 a complete dump may only consist of memory in use. If you don't expect all memory to be in use (or choose any other option than "complete memory dump") and want to save space you may reduce the size of dump allocated. If you select a Kernel only dump then you may save a significant amount of space by setting the size lower. Step 3 does not set any kind of size, it only sets the *type* of dump created.

Answer (score -1):

Dump options can be edited at Advanced properties, Startup and Recovery;
Start > Run > "control.exe sysdm.cpl,,3"

Leave page file on, as it is necessary for windows to work properly, it was a good idea once to turn it off, but just an idea.

Page = virtual ram, to store all stuff windows needs but isn't using and remove it from physical ram(in shortest terms) so you can play game IE.
Dump needs Vram to work as Mokubai mentioned